# I want to append my html from javascript without jQuery

Tags: javascript

.appendChild is not working for me, all I want to do is append the html code in my javascript const bottomText to the DOM without jQuery

```
   const bottomText = `
        <div class="bottom-text row">
          <div class="column column-left">test
            <p>xx%<span></span></p>
          </div>
          <div class="column column-right">
          <p>test</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        `;
document.getElementById("piechart").appendChild(bottomText);
```

And my html

```
<body>
    <div class="graphs">
        <div class="pie-chart" id="piechart">
        </div>
        <script src="./js/pie.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/linegraph.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>
```

Why does it not work? with jquery it works but for this project they want me to only use vanilla js

Comment: You mean, like `document.getElementById('targetDivId').innerHTML += 'myHTMLString'`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`appentChild()` takes a Node as a parameter. If you want to add string containing you can use `insertAdjacentHTML()`

```
document.getElementById("piechart").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",bottomText);
```

MDN Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

Comment: This is the proper solution. I would add the docs for completeness and to understend the first argument https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

Comment: @arieljuod If you want to edit the answer you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

To use `.appendChild()` for first you should create an element:

```
let element = document.createElement("div");
    document.body.appendChild(element);
```

Comment: For the record, I didn't downvote, but I may assume, there could be two reasons for that - your code simply creates empty `<div>` and appends that to the end of the target node (`body` in this case) and **NOT** inserts custom HTML. Second, could be, manipulating DOM in such a way could be way slower than appending HTML code directly with `insertAdjacentHTML()` as suggested by another answer. Which, by the way, I'm guessing, is the reason why `insertBefore()` answer didn't get that much upvotes.

Comment: `element.innerHTML = "some text"; `

Put any html code with `insertAdjacentHTML()` is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.insertBefore()`

> There is no insertAfter() method. It can be emulated by combining the insertBefore method with Node.nextSibling.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var node = document.createElement('li');

  node.innerHTML = '<strong>Water</strong>'

  var list = document.getElementById("myList1");
  list.insertBefore(node, list.childNodes[0]);
}
```

```html
<ul id="myList1">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
</ul>

<p>Click the button to move an item from one list to another</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```